# How to load bitmap from sprite sheet in easeljs

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am using easeljs library. I created a sprite sheet using sprite generator with all the assets(buttons,background images,icons, etc). I got a sprite sheet and a css file (contains co-ordinates, dimensions). I need to load every images in the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this [here](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/1320-how-to-load-bitmap-from-sprite-sheet-in-easeljs) on the CreateJS site:

> The best way is to preload the images using PreloadJS (http://preloadjs.com). There are a bunch of examples in the PreloadJS GitHub that should help with that. Additionally, 3 of the EaselJS demos use PreloadJS (Game, SpriteSheet, and Transform).
>
> Note that the images will automatically load one they are used - and they will show up once loaded, as long as you are updating the stage.